# how to detect newline characters as empty variables in bash?

Tags: bash

I have following sample code in bash file, where I am trying to detect empty variables after I read them from an array. (Note: I am getting an array from other application to bash)

Problem is I am not able to detect newline characters using `[[ -n "${var}" ]]` or using `[[ ${var} != "" ]]`

Following is my bash code.

```
#!/bin/bash

function test0 {
  echo "........test 0 start........"
  newline='
'
  test_arr=("${newline}" "${newline}" "${newline}")
  echo "Array Size     --> ${#test_arr[@]}"
  echo "Array Content  -->  ${test_arr[@]}"

  aa=${test_arr[0]}
  bb=${test_arr[1]}
  cc=${test_arr[2]}

  aa="x"

  [[ -n "${aa}" && -n "${bb}" && -n "${cc}" ]] || {
    echo "ERROR : Empty aa or bb or cc."
    # exit 1
  }
  echo "........test 0 end........"
}

function test1 {
  echo "........test 1 start........"
  test_arr=("" "" "")
  echo "Array Size     --> ${#test_arr[@]}"
  echo "Array Content  -->  ${test_arr[@]}"

  aa=${test_arr[0]}
  bb=${test_arr[1]}
  cc=${test_arr[2]}

  aa="x"

  [[ -n "${aa}" && -n "${bb}" && -n "${cc}" ]] || {
    echo "ERROR : Empty aa or bb or cc."
    # exit 1
  }
  echo "........test 1 end........"
}

function main {
  echo "........MAIN start........"
  test0
  echo "--------------------------"
  test1
  echo "........MAIN end........"
}

main
```

Above code prints following output

```
........MAIN start........
........test 0 start........
Array Size     --> 3
Array Content  -->  
 
 

........test 0 end........
--------------------------
........test 1 start........
Array Size     --> 3
Array Content  -->    
ERROR : Empty aa or bb or cc.
........test 1 end........
........MAIN end........
```

My Expectation for test0 is also to throw Error `"ERROR : Empty aa or bb or cc"`

Is there any short way I can achieve this in bash (without using `sed`/`awk` etc. on variables)

Comment: Why are you expecting a string that contains a newline character to be empty?

Comment: It sounds like a problem to be addressed when you build the array in the first place. Where are these strings coming from?

Comment: @chepner thanks, They are coming from. external python script. which prints on console, sometimes it prints empty lines, at bash side i have to make things fault tolerant

Comment: How are you loading the array? `readarray`, for example, has a `-t` option to strip the trailing newline from each line it reads from its standard input, so that `$'\n'` is read as `''`.

Comment: actually i am using readarray and mapfile, and i can not strip newline as they are valid and need to be preserved in non-empty string

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, how about:

```
  pat=$'^\n*$'    # pattern to match zero or more newline characters
  if [[ $aa =~ $pat || $bb =~ $pat || $cc =~ $pat ]]; then
    echo "ERROR : Empty aa or bb or cc."
    # exit 1
  fi
```

in place of

```
  [[ -n "${aa}" && -n "${bb}" && -n "${cc}" ]] || {
    echo "ERROR : Empty aa or bb or cc."
    # exit 1
  }
```

If you want to detect whitespaces, tabs, carriage returns and newlines as an
empty characters, assign `pat` to:

```
pat='^[[:space:]]*$'
```